# Error 207: ERR_CERT_INVALID

Tags: chrome, x509

I'm trying to make it so people can create a private key via the browser via the  element and then after have it so that an X.509 cert is sent to them that's then installed into the browser. But I can't seem to get it to work:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/x509/test.php

Every time I visit that page and send the new SPKAC (as generated by ) I get an error 207: ERR_CERT_INVALID in Google Chrome. The signing cert is has been imported into my browser as a CA cert.

I even tried it over https (on another server) and it didn't work there either.

The source (in the off chance that it matters):

http://pastebin.com/QkDA3pq0

Any ideas?

Comment: This is really a server config question. Flag this question for migration and we'll get it to the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your certificate is only valid for sh149.surpasshosting.com and www.sh149.surpasshosting.com, however your domain is www.frostjedi.com. This mismatch in domains is causing the browser's verification of the certificate to fail.

You will need to re-key the existing certificate, or get a new certificate for www.frostjedi.com. If you can post your cert provider, I can find details of how to do this.

If this is for a temporary or development system, you could consider using the free SSL capabilities of [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com/), however I would recommend against this if the certificate would be used for encrypting any form of live data.